# CMake configuration for multiple test files

Tags: c, cmake

I'm running into following error. Basically I've two test .c files, how can I've them run both independently? Each one having it's own main function?

> duplicate symbol _main in:
>
> CMakeFiles/Tests.dir/test.c.o
>
> CMakeFiles/Tests.dir/test2.c.o

**Root CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(Polymorphism)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

**src/CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_library(Polymorphism person.c employee.c)
target_include_directories(Polymorphism PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

**test/CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_executable(Tests test.c test2.c)
target_link_libraries(Tests Polymorphism)
```

**test/test.c**

```
void main() {
    // some tests
}
```

**test/test2.c**

```
void main() {
   // some tests
}
```

Comment: `how can I've them run both independently?` - What about simply creating **separate executables** for them? Otherwise your question is somehow unclear - you create single executable, but want to run tests independently.

Comment: By compiling each one separately, each with its own makefile. BTW your file  names are inconsistent. `test.c` or `test1.c`?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Multiple executables idea is good, and then is there a way to run all those executables together? Help with the code please

Comment: @WeatherVane fixed the typo. thanks

Comment: `run all those executables together?` - This seems to be an **actual problem**, isn't it? You may define *test* for each of your executables, then `make test` will run every test in nice fashion. `add_executable(test_executable test1.c)`, `add_test(NAME test1 COMMAND test_executable)`. See documentation for [add_test](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/add_test.html) command and [ctest](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/ctest.1.html).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'm not that fluent with CMake files, can you please help with an answer and the code.

Comment: Just follow any manual about testing in CMake. E.g. [this one](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Testing_With_CTest).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually quite simple to solve. CMake allows you to create multiple executables (These can have their own main function) and also contains a function [`add_test`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/add_test.html) used to bind these to tests.

So, given that you have files `test.c` and `test2.c`, each with their own main function:

```
add_executable(test1 test.c)
add_executable(test2 test2.c)

add_test(NAME t1 COMMAND test1)
add_test(NAME t2 COMMAND test2)
```

Now, you can run the commands `make test` or `ctest`, which will register two separate tests and run them as such.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to run both tests with one command, like `add_test(NAME t1 COMMAND test1 COMMAND test2)`

Comment: @App2015, no, since each test is bound to one command. I am unsure if `add_custom_command` might work, however. I doubt that you actually need both tests in one executable. It doesn't make sense for one executable to have two main functions. Similarly, `make test` _and_ `ctest` are both just _one_ command, so I don't see a problem...